# Binding an event to an element in a view returned by ajax on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, php-5.3

I have a button that maes an AJAX request and fills a div with the view that is returned. Then I would like it to bind 1 click event to a button that is a DOM elements inside the view that is returned.

This is my handler for the first AJAX call that gets a view back.

```
// gets the next question or video
$("#next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });

    var host = "http://" + window.location.hostname;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : host + "/next",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#test-content').html(data);
            $("#submit-question").bind('submit', attempt(e));
        }
    },"json");
});
```

This is the attempt() function that I want to attach to the event. This makes it so I can make another AJAX call from a form. Or at least I thought it would.

```
function attempt(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajaxSetup({
         headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
      });

      // input data
      var question_id = $('input:hidden[name=question_id]').val();
      var attempt =  $("input[name=attempt]").val();

      var dataString = 'question_id='+question_id+'&attempt='+attempt;

      var host = "http://" + window.location.hostname;

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url : host + "/attempt",
          data : dataString,
          success : function(data){
          console.log(data);
              $('#show-answer').html(data);
              $('#next-button').show();
          }
      },"json");

 }
```

So my problem is that, can't figure out why, but the attempt() function runs instantly after the first ajax call is made. And it never binds the event to the button. The ajax calls are made one after another with no delay. Also not sure if I could just put `e` in the attempt() call like I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling attempt, not assigning it

```
$("#submit-question").bind('submit', attempt(e));
```

needs to be

```
$("#submit-question").bind('submit', attempt);
```

You could also just avoid assigning each time the html is changed. You can use event delegation and capture the submit event further up the DOM tree.

```
$('#test-content').on("submit", "#submit-question" , attempt);
```

Comment: Thanks worked great. So the submit event will already pass the EventObject into the function. I am still confused on the .on that you use. So is this saying that if any submit-question id submits will use attempt() and does not need to be rebinded every time?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, try this:

```
 $('#test-content').html(data);
 $("#test-content").on('submit','#submit-question',function(){ attempt(e)});
```

Comment: `e` would be undefined in attempt

Comment: no, it would use the e from the call. $("#next").click(function(e)

Comment: Sorry it would not be undefined, but it it the wrong event.

Comment: Fair enough, but just using the code that was provided by the OP.